# Admob 4.0.4 and Json is not compatible to use together

Tags: android

i am having this error..
with **admob version 4.0.4** and **josecgomez.com.android.webservices.json.jar**

As both have many files in common(with pkg and file names). 
JVM is not able to load these files.

What version of both, i should use to get rid of this Problem.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to the previous version. It seems they broke it when they created the new Google version of the SDK.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, which version you used to remove the error. talking about admob version or json version??

Comment: I reverted to a previous version of the AdMob library